# Using excel to count with conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet that looks like this (with many more columns and rows of course):

| condition a | condition b | condition c | condition d | result (a,b) | result (c,d) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| yes | no | yes | no | 0 | 1 |
| no | no | no | yes | 0 | 1 |
| yes | yes | no | no | 1 | 0 |

...

Now, I only want to separately count the occurrences of either a or b  or both are occurring **per row**, but want to exclude all instances where either a or b (or both) are occurring together with c or d, since I want to count the occurrences where either c or d or both are apperearing separetely. I have toyed around with the idea of using the `countifs`, but my problem is that I want to count every row separately, so if a and b occur together I only want to count them once, so if I applied `countifs` to all the colums together, it would count **all** instances of yes in the a and b column.

For example here in the first row, I would get a 1 for c,d and a 0 for a,b since while there is a yes for a in the first row, there is also one for c.
In the second row, we only have yes for d so it's easy that it's easyily 1 for c,d and 0 for a,b.

And finally in the third row we only have a,b both yes, so it's 1 for a,b since I want to know the occurence per row, and since there is no for both c and d, and so it's 0 for c,d since both are no.

Does anyone know how to solve this in excel? Thank you all for your help

Comment: Do a countifs() for each row or else something like and(c2="no",or(a2="yes",b2="yes")) assuming row 2 is first row of data.

Comment: so given the data you provided, what would be the count and why? please detail each row.

Comment: @SolarMike thanks for the tip, that had been my thought now as well, but how do I implement that several "yes" only get count only once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AND and OR (COLUMN E):

```
=--AND(AND(C2<>"yes",D2<>"yes"),OR(A2="yes",B2="yes"))
```

And (COLUMN F)

```
=--OR(D2="yes",C2="yes")
```

[image]

If you want to count without the helper columns:

A,B:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((C2:C4<>"yes")*(D2:D4<>"yes"))*((A2:A4="yes")+(B2:B4="yes")>0))
```

C,D:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--((C2:C4="yes")+(D2:D4="Yes")>0))
```

[image]